# awaiting on socket connection and channel at the same time

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a go routine which needs to wait on a socketconnection (incoming message from client) and also there is a channel which it reads from, both at the same time.  Not sure how to do that in a go routine of if its even possible? Any sample code will be appriciated.

I've seen how to do it on channels https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations, but I have a combination of a websocket and a channel.

From this post https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/issues/122 it dos not seem possible (I'm using gorilla) but this is old and was wondering if there was something new.

Answer (score 0):

To wait on two event streams at the same time in Go, you'd use the `select` statement, but it only works on channels.

So the canonical solution is have a goroutine that reads from the socket (blocking) and places the data onto a channel. Then you can `select` on this channel together with some other channel.

Pseudocode:

```
// Want to wait on channel 'chan' and socket connection 'conn'

// sockCh is used to notify of new data arrived on the socket
sockCh := make(chan []byte)

// This goroutine listens on the socket and pushes all data it gets
// into sockCh.
go func() {
  for {
    buf := make([]byte, 2048)
    n, err := conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
      log.Println("read error", err)
      return
    }
    if n == 0 {
      return
    }
    sockCh <- buf
  }
}()

select {
case buf := <-sockCh:
  // got buf from socket
case stuff := <-chan:
  // got stuff from channel
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I had in mind as well, just wanted to confirm the approach before I went ahead with it.

Comment: This works, but the Go routine is not cleaned up. It will be waiting for that `Read` to complete regardless of what happens, until the connection is closed.